# how to send email from web app with mail() in php on CentOS (sendmail, postfix, ...?)

Tags: php, linux, centos, sendmail, postfix-mta

We are building a web app and will need to send emails on a frequent basis using php's mail() function. We are using it to send mails when e.g. a user signs up for the app, when a client has a new product order, and so on.

What do we install best on our CentOS server to make this happen? I've read a lot about sendmail vs. postfix vs. other packages to use as an MTA but couldn't figure out what I need.

We will not run mail boxes for our users, we only want to send out email from our web app, not receive any emails (we are using google apps for that)

We are looking for a solutions that is easy to setup and maintain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need only send emails from a PHP application the only thing you need is to install sendmail. AFAIR you don't even need to configure it.

Comment: Well, you do have to configure it .. but in most cases the .deb / .rpm post install scripts handle that for you as long as you set the hostname / etc prior to installing it.

Comment: @Tim Post So you don't have to in most cases ;)
This is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already mail server, I would suggest have a look to SSMTP, its [configuration](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/SSMTP) is very easy to just relay the mails to your server.

Comment: is it better than sendmail/postfix for some reason?

Comment: SSMTP is great if you just want to relay mail to an actual MTA. I use it on my desktop.

Comment: In this case, would using SSMTP be useful for sending mail from a VPS to my gmail google apps hosted email instead?

Answer (score 0):

Agreed that you'll only need unconfigured sendmail for outbound.  You could use PHP's Mail function but I would recommend looking at Pear::Mail and Pear::Mail_Mime packages for PHP.  They can be configured to use Sendmail for outbound, and are also great for embedding images as well as implementing native multi-part MIME email format support.  This is ideal if you want your messages to have embedded HTML, Images, and as well as have the ability to gracefully degrade to straight plain-text.  Also, something else to consider.  You should add a SPF record on your domain for the webhost that's doing the mailing, and also add a TXT record so you don't trip SPAM filters on the recipient side.